# About reverse operation

Tags: python

I am new to Python just for my own interest.  I am taking the introductory course from eDX.  I would like to understand why when I run the following code, the reverse function will reverse both the reverse_fours list and the original all_fours

```
all_fours = fours + more_fours
reverse_fours = all_fours
print("All ",all_fours)
print("Reverse ",reverse_fours)
reverse_fours.reverse()
print("All ",all_fours)
print("Reverse ",reverse_fours)
```

Comment: `=` is an assignment operator. whatever changes occurs in reverse_fours will occur in all_fours.

Comment: Read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html